# Add line to index file to avoid page number

Tags: write, makeindex

Is it possible to write custom lines into the index-file?

Consider this:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[splitindex]{imakeidx}

\makeindex[name=date]

\newcommand\dateindex[1]{\index[date]{#1}}

\begin{document}
 \section{Diary, April 4th, 1891}
 \dateindex{1891!04!27}

Just some text

\immediate\write\@indexfile{???}{}


   \printindex[date]
   \end{document}
```

My question is: How do i change this

```
\immediate\write\@indexfile{???}{}
```

to write something without pagenumber into the idx file?

Of course this does not make any sense as I could just use an sty-file. But in my final version I would have dates and page numbers for those part of the book that are not within a diary entry.

Comment: What kind of output do you want?  Do you want to have the index entry just list the date?

Comment: Exactly! That's what I am looking for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this example shows a simple method for suppressing the page number,
as well as the comma.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\newcommand{\idxnopage}[1]{{}}
\providecommand{\gobble}[1]{{}}
\newcommand{\idxsechead}[1]{\textbf{#1}\gobble}
\makeindex

\begin{document}
Here is some text\index{some text} that we want indexed.

We also want a ``header'' in the index.

\index{00@\idxsechead{Header} |idxnopage}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

the resulting index:

[image: output of example code]

of course, you are responsible for creating an appropriate sort field
so these entries sort into the desired order.

**update:**
according to a comment by @florian, this does not work with `xindy`.

it *does* work with `imakeindex` as long as `makeindex` is used as the back end.

Comment: For whoever else might be trying to use this solution: Unfortunately it doesn't work with `xindy` which ignores  "unknown attribute `idxnopage'!"

Comment: I.e.: not directly: To use it you'll need to define idxnopage in the style file used, cf below

Comment: @Fiorian -- i'll add a note to the answer to say it works only with `makeindex`, and not with `xindy`. you say that to use `xindy` one "needs to define `\idxnopage` in the style file uses", but you're not specific *which* style file.  please be specific (and that would be a userul answer).

Comment: You saved my day. I would like to add one thing: it is very tempting to define a `\newcommand{\iindex}[2]{\index{#1@\idxsechead{#2} |idxnopage}}`, but it won't work. One have to leave it as it is.

Answer (score 1):

This provides `\dateindex` for adding the page number and `\dateindex*` for suppressing it.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{imakeidx}

\makeindex[name=date]

\makeatletter
\newcommand\dateindex{\@ifstar{\dateindex@noshow}{\index[date]}}
\newcommand\dateindex@noshow[1]{\index[date]{#1|noshowdate}}
\let\noshowdate\@gobble
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Not in the diary\dateindex{1892!04!27}\dateindex{1892!05!27}

\section{Diary, April 4th, 1891}
\dateindex*{1891!04!04}

\section{Diary, April 5th, 1891}
\dateindex*{1891!04!05}

Just some text

\printindex[date]

\end{document}
```

If you want to suppress the comma in the “no page” entries, you need a style file.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{checkcomma.ist}
delim_0 "\\checkcomma"
delim_1 "\\checkcomma"
delim_2 "\\checkcomma"
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{imakeidx}

\makeindex[name=date,options=-s checkcomma]

\makeatletter
\newcommand\dateindex{\@ifstar{\dateindex@noshow}{\index[date]}}
\newcommand\dateindex@noshow[1]{\index[date]{#1|noshowdate}}
\let\noshowdate\@gobble
\newcommand\checkcomma{\@ifnextchar\noshowdate{}{, }}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Not in the diary\dateindex{1892!04!27}\dateindex{1892!05!27}

\section{Diary, April 4th, 1891}
\dateindex*{1891!04!04}

\section{Diary, April 5th, 1891}
\dateindex*{1891!04!05}

Just some text

\printindex[date]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Great, thanks! Is there a possibility to remove the comma at the end? Or do I have to use a style file?

Comment: @MartinMueller For that you need a makeindex style. I think it has already been covered on the site.